# Modelling rooms for games

Tags: modeling, game-engine

I am developing a "show-room" game for HTC VIVE. For it I am modelling some enviroment, which is just a building with two rooms and a garten at the front side.

At the moment it looks like that
Outside:
[image: Outside]
Inside:
[image: Inside]

How you see there a a lot of edge loops I created to model the room/building. 
My question is should I now try to delete all of them that I dont need to minimize polys or should I let it how it is? Or should I make a copy of it, useful if I want to change sth after, but the production one should be optimized having only the needed loops?

Here an example of what I mean, where I deleted all edges, that I dont need.Here I saved like 300 polys only, since I am not using any SubSurf or sth....

[image: Outside_LowPoly]

Comment: Worry about good topology before optimization, in other words leave them

Comment: There are some completely redundant edge loops, those can definitely be removed. Don't remove anything that could compromise your ability to easily tweak it later, though.

Comment: Why do you think you need all these little faces (now or in future)? Do you plan doors and windows? Btw. the refined model seems to have some issues: I can see two face centers at the roof and at the garden ground (not even in center). Why the garden wall still consists of three quads?

Comment: Just to let you know any answer to your question will be opinion based.